# G++ Link-time optimisation on Mac - compiler/linker bug?

Tags: c++, macos, gcc

I have a project that uses OpenMP (which doesn't seem to be available in the current OS X default clang setup) but would also like to use LTO. I have sections of the code in SIMD intrinsics using SSE4 and found that G++ was unable to link this code without using the OS X provided clang linker (flag `-Wa,-q`). G++ 5.10 is installed via Homebrew and compiled with without multilib.

I can compile with LTO using clang but then I lose the parallel 'for's, when I add `-flto` to G++ I get:

```
lto1: internal compiler error: in add_symbol_to_partition_1, at lto/lto-partition.c:211

lto1: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
g++-5: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program lto1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues> for instructions.
lto-wrapper: fatal error: g++-5 returned 4 exit status
compilation terminated.
collect2: fatal error: lto-wrapper returned 1 exit status
compilation terminated.
```

This also occurs without `-Wa,-q` if I remove the intrinsics so that it can compile the remaining code.

I have tried a simple two file program that compiles fine with LTO in G++ so I'm not sure what the problem is. Whilst LTO doesn't seem to make a huge amount of difference to this code, in clang I've measured about 7% which is non-negligible as the program takes a while to run.

I know the error says to submit a bug report but I don't want to unless I know it's not just my own stupidity.

Does anyone have experience of this sort of problem, or have I actually run into a compiler bug? (haven't come across one before to my knowledge)

Cheers!

Comment: The compiler should not crash at any time during compilation, so it's definitely a compiler bug - even if your code is "bad", it should either give an error or succeed [it is possible, if your code is affected by Undefined Behaviour that the generated code does something undefined, but crashing the compiler during compilation is NOT within the set of allowed things]

Comment: @MatsPetersson Thanks, going to submit a report, the error doesn't occur at `O0`, which seems strange to me. I'm fairly sure it's not UB as the software is written with strict standard compliance to compile on different systems and compilers.

Comment: @Goobley: It doesn't matter if it's undefined behavior. The compiler should __never__ report an ICE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilers are **never** supposed to report ICEs. It's a bug. It may already be a reported bug, but it is most certainly a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I'll submit a proper report then, interestingly I noticed that -flto doesn't cause the ICE at `O0`, I haven't replicated it in a reasonable sized example yet, so I'll try and do that first.

Comment: -O0 even with -flto I think means "don't optimise", so it could have something to do with it.